# Dynamically Set WixUIBannerBmp Location Based on Property

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

I have the following:

`<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="FirstBanner.jpg" />`

I want to be able to set the value of this `WixVariable` using a property that gets passed in when the installer is kicked off:

`msiexec.exe /i MyInstaller.msi /l* install.log MYPROPERTY=SomeValue`

So, based on the the value of `MYPROPERTY`, I set the value of the `WixVariable` to one of two (or more) values.

My initial stab at this proved unsuccessful:

```
<Property Id="BANNERLOCATION" Value="FirstBanner.jpg" />
<WixVariable Id="WixUIBannerBmp" Value="[BANNERLOCATION]" />
```

I get the following build error:

`error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file '[BANNERLOCATION]'.`

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? This is simply branding the install based on a passed-in property, after all ...

Comment: Most likely the banner is stored in the Binary table, so you cannot change it dynamically during install. Also, the error suggests that the formatted reference to BANNERLOCATION cannot be resolved, so you cannot use a property for WixUIBannerBmp.

Comment: Have you investigated transforms? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367447(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what you are trying to accomplish is not supported by the Windows Installer. Sorry.